# Need some design advice for a document control site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

What's the best way to implement this?

1. User click on a given "Country"
2. A page is displayed with all the "Processes" for that Country
3. user click on a "Process" or "Sub-Process" (from step 2 )
4. A page is loaded with all the documents for that Process or Sub-Process

Using SharePoint 2010 (however I can use 2013 if that's a better choice). if anyone can suggest a blog that would be even better.

Answer (score -1):

Use a library with custom document set type for processes and for sub processes.